# How can I set up email notification when an error is encountered in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I have some reports that are configured for email delivery in reporting services. Last night we experienced some network outtages and reporting services was unable to connect to the database engine.

Is there any way to configure email notifications to be sent out when a subscription cannot be delivered?

I am using reporting services 2008 R2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(You want an email when email can't be delivered?)

Directly within SSRS this can't be done. But you could have a SQL agent monitor the status of the subscriptions. The SQL agent can be configured to send email pretty easily. The status of the last run is stored in the subscriptions table.

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deanka/archive/2009/01/13/diagnosing-and-troubleshooting-subscriptions.aspx

```
select
'SubnDesc' = s.Description,
'SubnOwner' = us.UserName,
'LastStatus' = s.LastStatus,
'LastRun' = s.LastRunTime,
'ReportPath' = c.Path,
'ReportModifiedBy' = uc.UserName,
'ScheduleId' = rs.ScheduleId,
'SubscriptionId' = s.SubscriptionID
from ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions s
join ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c on c.ItemID = s.Report_OID
join ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs on rs.SubscriptionID = s.SubscriptionID
join ReportServer.dbo.Users uc on uc.UserID = c.ModifiedByID
join ReportServer.dbo.Users us on us.UserID = s.OwnerId
join msdb.dbo.sysjobs j on j.name = CONVERT(nvarchar(128),rs.ScheduleId)
```

But none of these methods queue the email: they try, and if there is a network problem they give lose the email. You could possibly install a SMTP relay on your Reporting Services machine to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below the script will send notification too..


--Below script can be used to send the Notification everyday morning to your email id. 

DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @FileCreationDate varchar(20)

SET @COUNT = (SELECT count(*)
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions s
WHERE (s.LastStatus LIKE 'Failure%' OR s.LastStatus LIKE 'Error%')
AND s.LastRunTime > DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE()))

IF @COUNT >0 
BEGIN

    SET @tableHTML =
        N'<H1>SSRS Report Subscription Failures</H1>' +
        N'<table border="1" bgcolor="##F0F0E0" >' + 
        N'<font color = "White"> <tr><th BGCOLOR ="#008080"> ScheduleID</th><th BGCOLOR ="#008080">Name</th>' +
        N'<th BGCOLOR ="#008080">Description</th><th BGCOLOR ="#008080">DeliveryExtension</th><th BGCOLOR ="#008080">LastStatus</th>' +    N'<th BGCOLOR ="#008080">LastRunTime</th>' +      
        N'<th BGCOLOR ="#008080">Path</th></tr> </font>' +
        CAST ( ( select 
        TD = sc.ScheduleID , '', 
        TD = c.Name , '', 
        TD = sb.[Description] , '', 
        TD = sb.DeliveryExtension , '', 
        TD = sb.LastStatus , '', 
        TD = sb.LastRunTime , '', 
        TD = c.Path  
        FROM ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rs
        INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Schedule sc ON rs.ScheduleID = sc.ScheduleID
        INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sb ON rs.SubscriptionID = sb.SubscriptionID
        INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] c ON rs.ReportID = c.ItemID AND sb.Report_OID = c.ItemID
        WHERE (sb.LastStatus LIKE 'Failure%' OR sb.LastStatus LIKE 'Error%')
        AND sb.LastRunTime > DATEADD(D, -1, GETDATE())
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
        N'</table>' ;

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='Mailid',
        @subject = 'SSRS Subscription Failures',
        @body = @tableHTML,
        @body_format = 'HTML' ;
END
```