# Getting Notifed of Fail Reporting Services Failed Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services

We have quite a few reports that run on schedules, and invariably sometimes they fail. I would like to pre-empt these issues and get a notification when ever a failure happens on the server.

Has anyone got a way of doing this?

Cheers
Luke

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770984/how-can-i-set-up-email-notification-when-an-error-is-encountered-in-reporting-se/7773372#7773372