# SSRS - Drops Notification Setting

Tags: email, reporting-services, notifications

This problem is different from the "Duplicate Question" because as we read through my question, we will see that the issue is that the Email SETTINGS are being removed/dropped/deleted.

I've got an SSRS platform that I'm trying to get to send email notifications on report creation failure. The problem is that after I set up the report to send Notifications, it will eventually remove these settings.  I'm not sure how or why this is happening.

[image: Setting of the notification]

A few minutes later after I have told the report to run.

[image: Empty]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up email notification when an error is encountered in reporting services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770984/how-can-i-set-up-email-notification-when-an-error-is-encountered-in-reporting-se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you modify the subscription the underlying job is recreated, so previous configurations set on it are deleted.

Just create/modify the subscription and only then set the notification, If you configured the Database Mail and Operator correctly you will be notified.